# Change color - length of word in <td>

Tags: javascript, css, colors, counter

If i have text in a `<span>` the code works well, but when i set the same class on a `<td>` the code ignores text inside the element.

HTML

```
<span class="inner">+455222333444</span>
<td class="inner">+455222333444</td>`
```

jQuery

```
$('.inner').css('color', function(){    
  return $(this).text().trim().length > 10 ? 'red' : 'blue';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply color to your `td` element, you need to wrap your `td` in `table`, `tbody` and `tr` tag.

```js
$('.inner').css('color', function(){    
    return $(this).text().trim().length > 10 ? 'red' : 'blue';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="inner">+455222333444</span>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td class="inner">+455222333444</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @OliverTothHajdu, I am happy to help